# GCC C/C++ double behavior

Tags: c++, c, gcc, double

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ double precision and rounding off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875007/c-double-precision-and-rounding-off)

Code:

```
int main(void)
{
    double a = 12;
    double b = 0.5;
    double c = 0.1;

    std::cout.precision(25);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    std::cout << a + b << std::endl;
    std::cout << a + c << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
12
0.5
0.1000000000000000055511151
12.5
12.09999999999999964472863
```

Why does GCC represent 0.1 and 0.5 differently? When adding, they are represented differently. It seems 0.5 and whole numbers a represented differently that other floats. Or is this just something going on in the io library?
What causes this behavior?

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098558/float-vs-double-precision).

Comment: Doubles don't have infinite precision. The values you're assigning are not representable exactly using doubles.

Comment: I've clarified my question. It's not about precision.

Comment: @toor I suspect you will find the answer to why certain numbers give a better representation than others in "What every computer scientist should know..." article as well.

Comment: it is. 0.1 is for floating point encoding the same thing as 1/3 for decimal encoding. It's an infinite series of digits. You only have 53 binary digits (as far as I remember) which boils down to around 18 decimal digits. Please read the paper presented below. It helps.

Comment: @iammilind: The "C++ double precision" is not a duplicate. That asker wants to control the rounding, while this one is asking why he's not getting the exact answer. That said I am sure I've seen questions answered with link to "What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic" and those would probably be duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as decimal numbers with a finite number of digits can only exactly represent numbers that are a sum of powers of 10, binary floating point numbers can only exactly represent numbers that are a sum of powers of 2.

In this case, `0.1` cannot be represented as a finite sum of powers of 2, whereas `0.5` and `12` can (`0.5` is equal to 2<sup>-1</sup> and `12` is equal to 2<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup>).

As a further example, 0.75 can also be exactly represented in binary floating point, because it can be expressed as 2<sup>-1</sup> + 2<sup>-2</sup>.

Answer (score 4):

0.1 can not be exactly represented in binary as it is not a power of 2 and must be represented by a number that is really, really, really close instead. This is why students are taught never to use the `==` operator when comparing floating-point numbers and banking applications almost always store money as two integers, the dollar amount and the number of pennies.

Comment: Of course. But that leads me to perhaps my answer. Is 0.5 stored differently? This was really my question. Sometimes code is not enough to express your amusement.

Answer (score 4):

the default answer for these questions:

[What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/goldberg.pdf)

basically, it's the inaccuracy of the floating point encoding. You have around 17 significant digits and doing arithmetic operations reduces them.

Comment: I've clarified my question. It's not about precision.

Comment: [Reader-friendly](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) version of the same article.

Answer (score 0):

read this

http://floating-point-gui.de/