# How to round a double to the nearest 10th place

Tags: java, double, rounding

```
public double hypotenuse()
{       
    //return Math.hypot(leg, leg); //returns 7.0710678118654755
    //return 0.1 * Math.floor(Math.hypot(leg, leg) * 10); //returns 7.0
    //return 0.1 * Math.ceil(Math.hypot(leg, leg) * 10); //returns 7.1000000000000005
    return 0.1 * Math.round(Math.hypot(leg, leg) * 10); //returns 7.1000000000000005
}
```

I am trying to round to the nearest 10th place, so this number should round up to 7.1.  Why does this method work with Math.floor but not with Math.round?   Does anyone have any insight?

Thanks,

Sky

Comment: What is this language?

Comment: Different language, but likely on-point: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6875007/239394.  It appears to me that you are just experiencing double-precision rounding issues.

Comment: It's for an assignment.  It was specified to use a double and round to the nearest tenth place. I'll keep BigDecimal in mind though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to your answer to yourself, you don't want to convert an object of type A to type B, operate on it, and then convert it back to type A. Not if you can do anything else.

The following does what you want it to do:

```
public double hypotenuse()
{
    return Math.round(Math.hypot(leg, leg) * 10) / 10.0;
}
```

I'm not entirely sure why. It would take some digging into what this compiles down to at the assembly level.

The *real problem* is that each double in Java only has a limited number of bits to store its decimal portion. There are an infinite number of possible real numbers in real life. There is no way you can represent every single real number with only 64 bits. This is why you should avoid floating point calculations in banking apps and software that requires the number to be exact. Multiplying a few doubles together can introduce quite a significant error margin in the calculation. [See this explanation on another SO answer, which does a great job of explaining this further.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-doubles-in-java)

If you really need it to be exact, use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: I knew there was a way to do it with one line of code!  And I swear I tried this and it didn't work, but it's working now.  Thank you! :-)  I've run into this rounding issue in several programs now and it has caused me so much stress! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. If you care about perfect precision, though, you should really use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @Skylin, may I ask why you care so much about the numbers being exact?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, this is what I found that works.

```
public double hypotenuse()
{       
    double hypot = Math.hypot(leg, leg);
    String str = String.format("%1.1f", hypot);
    hypot = Double.valueOf(str);
    return hypot;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If this is for JS:

The Math.round() function returns the value of a number rounded to the nearest integer.

Comment: But does it round the the nearest **10th** place?

Comment: For Java, sorry.  And so does Math.floor and that works.  That's okay though, I found something different that works.